# swift generics - protocol concrete type

Tags: swift, generics

When I want create specialized class from generics I get this error:

```
error: using 'P2' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'P1' is not supported
```

From code:

```
protocol P1 {
    func foo()
}

protocol P2: P1 {

}

class C1<T: P1> {

}

class C2: C1<P2> {

}
```

I don't understand why it is not possible. Is known some workaround?

Comment: As Martin said (before the comment was deleted due to the dupe close), `P2` does not conform to `P1`. Depending on your exact situation, you probably want to build a type erased `AnyP2` wrapper, then talk in terms of `C1<AnyP2>`.

Comment: @Hamish The lack of language support for existential types strikes again :(

Comment: @Alexander There are some good reasons why this limitation exists, namely static protocol requirements (which I go into detail in [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878)) – but yeah, it's a shame the compiler doesn't currently make a distinction between protocols with and without static requirements.

Comment: @Hamish Oh that's an interesting edge case I didn't foresee. Welcome to type system design, I suppose :p